# Azure Data Factory - Error - "The cluster has been halted and is not restartable"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

**** **EDIT** **** The problem seems to have solved by itself. Still not sure how, so if anybody has any leads, I would be grateful for an answer.

---

What could be the cause of the following error **"The cluster has been halted and is not restartable" in Azure Data Factory Copy Data activity**:

```
Error details
Error code 2200

Failure type
User configuration issue

Details
Failure happened on 'Source' side.
ErrorCode=UserErrorHttpStatusCodeIndicatingFailure,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=The HttpStatusCode 500 indicates failure.
The cluster has been halted and is not restartable.
,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Source Pipeline
**pl_pipelinename**
```

Comment: What's your source type? json?

Comment: Yes, source type is JSON @JosephXu

Comment: Recently, it seems that there is a problem with ADF previewing the json format in the data flow and the json preview type needs to be set on the `source`. Is this the same for you ?

Comment: @JosephXu Where exactly  can I set the JSON preview type? Could not find anything in the Source tab of my Copy Data activity

Comment: I means data flow, you are using  Copy Data activity. Maybe yourhttp server has an error and returns a 500 error.

Comment: Hi@jeppoo1 Is there any update on this question? Can you share with us?

Comment: @JosephXu I edited the beginning of my question "The problem seems to have solved by itself. Still not sure how, so if anybody has any leads, I would be grateful for an answer.", it seems that something has corrected the error and I have no idea what has happened. I'm sorry, I hope someone else will have a more detailed answer on this in the future

Comment: It feels like a bug. Recently the data factory has made some updates, maybe some bugs have been fixed. We can see updateds [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/tag/azure-data-factory/).

Answer (score 1):

According the error message, it is difficult for us to find the cause of the problem. It looks like a bug. Recently the data factory has made some updates, maybe some bugs have been fixed. We can see updates history [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/tag/azure-data-factory/). After that, this issue was solved by itself.